# Encoding or Mapping

Tags: machine-learning

I am a bit confuse about how to handle categorical data for machine learning algorithm. There are some ways that I found on the internet, which are: Encoding only, Encoding followed by OneHotEncoding, and mapping with number 1, 2, 3, etc.
Can someone help me to understand when to use each of those ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways by which you can encode your categories depending on the nature of your data. It also depends on the algorithm that you're going to use as you can't use the same method of encoding for every model. Based on your method of encoding, you might even need to change your model cross validation strategy to avoid leakage.

Check this out - https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-categorical-variable-encoding-305f3361fd02